# Multiple database instances for testing

Tags: database

I'm working on an eclipse plugin that will connect to a relational database and generate code based on its metadata.

For testing, I thought about connecting to different database flavors and check for specific bugs.

My question is: What is the best approach on this situation?

Installing many different instances on my computer seems to be an overkill. I searched for public instances of databases (since the data doesn't matter) and couldn't find any. I also haven't found any kind of tool for it.

Does anyone knows a way to ease this process?

Comment: Why does having multiple databases seem like overkill?  Presumably, if you wanted to test on multiple operating systems you'd have multiple operating systems installed locally (presumably on VMs).  If you wanted to test with multiple application servers you'd have multiple app servers installed (again, potentially on VMs).  If you want to test against multiple browsers, you'd have multiple browsers installed (generally in VMs so you can test old versions).  Why wouldn't you have multiple databases (potentially on VMs)?

Comment: How is installing the software you explicitly want to target "overkill"?

Comment: I'm not talking about installing 2 or 3 engines, but 30+ of them. That's several GB of downloads, used disk space and time to install and configure them. That's what I meant to say with overkill.

Comment: You **will** have to install each and every DBMS you want to support. you can make life easier by installing them into a VM (e.g. VirtualBox). For some DBMS, you even might find pre-configured VMs ("appliances"), e.g. DB2. But 30+ seems a far fetched. I don't think there are more than maybe 15 DBMS that you need to take into account. With less then 10 you probably have > 90% of all potential users covered. And disk space is cheap...

Comment: Or use Docker; often easier. In any case, seems to be OT at this point.

Comment: I agree that 30 is a big number, but I don't make the requirements